# When you ___ at the course, you ___ straight to the registration desk

Tags: tense

When you __ at the course, you __ straight to the registration desk.

A) will arrive / have to go

B) have arrived / had to go

C) arrived / will have gone

D) arrive / are to go

E) had arrived / could go

I'm confused between the options "A" and "D". Can anyone explain every option whether it is true or not?

Answer (score 1):

(D) is the correct option here. Reason being the subject-verb tense agreement.

If you say **arrived**, you will need to say **would have gone** to preserve the correctness of tense aspects.

**have arrived** with **had to go** is not correct because the sequence would be muddled up. You are first going to the desk and then arriving? Nah.

**have arrived** is *present perfect* whereas **had to go** is *past tense*.

These sites can help you further to learn about tenses:

http://de.bab.la/konjugieren/englisch/arrive

http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/go.html

Comment: But there is only one correct answer. So either (A) or (D) is correct.

Comment: Edited the answer. D is the correct one.

Comment: Agree, D is grammatically correct.